# Partial solution for Eclipse/Android : "No resource found that matches the given name" and "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

Tags: android, eclipse, resources, r.java-file

after 6 hours of searching for solutions for this error, i've found one that works for me...partial.

I deleted my complete workspace and restarted eclipse. 
Now i pressed **Import -> General -> Existing Projects Into Workspace -> Select root directory -> Browse -> Path of your sdk (open SDK Manager, u can see it in the upper left corner) +extras\android\support\v7 -> select the first entry (android-support-v7-appcompat) -> check "copy projects into workspace" -> finish -> lots of errors appears->rigth click on the appcombat project -> Android -> check Android 5.0 -> Ok -> clean project**.

Getting to my problem:
**if i now create a new *blank project*, first a lots of errors appears and the src-folder is empty. Now i click right on the project -> properties -> android -> check Android 5.0 -> scroll down, remove the appcombat library -> add -> select the just constructed new appcombat project**. Now the Errors disappear but my src folder is still empty, even after cleaning. Only if i select ***empty project*** instead of blank one, an activity is created in the src folder, but just with the onCreate method.

Creating a blank project creates normally also some Menus i think (i'm new to android). Furthermore, now i have to change the Project Build Target to Android 5.0 and add the new appcombat project everytime i create a new project.

Does anybody knows an easier solution? I've read all the threads to this error but found no other solution than this one until now.

Thank you and best regards
Nils

Comment: MAke sure you are using the latest **Android Tools** library. Also make sure you do `Help/Check for Updates` after updating your SDK.

Comment: i've already done this..everything is up to date.